# "burning" vs "burn out" vs "burn up"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> My phone charger started **burning up** when I plugged it into the
>   outlet.
>
> My phone charger started **burning out** when I plugged it into the
>   outlet.
>
> My phone charger started **burning** when I plugged it into the outlet.

What's the difference between these 3 verbs, and how should I use them?

Comment: Have you tried looking up "burn up" and "burn out" as phrasal verbs?

Comment: Yes, but people use both verbs interchangeably sometimes, for instance, **to burn up** means to catch on fire and burn completely, and to **burn out** means when something stops working due to the damage caused when it started burning. I've heard people say **"My charger started burning up or my charger burned up"** when they really meant **"My charger burned out"**

Comment: Why say started to x when you mean x? That does not make sense.

Comment: The fact even native speakers jumble things up sometimes is neither here nor there. They have different meanings.

Comment: "My charger started burning up" would not be said for: My charger burned out. I think native speakers would know the difference. One is the result and the other is the process.

Comment: I work in a phone shop, so, I think that the people saying burned up instead of burned out are just making a big deal out of it then.

Answer (score 3):

burn up = catch fire and be consumed by it. We say a person has a fever and is burning up. [idiom]

burn out= no longer work or run. Including when a person has burn out (exhaustion at a job)

burn=fire appeared.

Usually, people burn things or things are burned and **when completely burned, they are said to be burned up.** A burned out house, for example.

by the way, a phone cannot really **start** burning out. It can be **burned out** or it can burn out. Like a light bulb: they burn out. You wouldn't usually say start to burn out. Candles can burn out,too, no longer have a flame as the wax is consumed.

Your phone (suddenly) charger **caught fire** when you plugged it in. You can say: started burning up here too.

Comment: This gets my +1, though I would also note that the meaning you ascribe to fever by idiom is also used, in my experience, for anything that's distinctly hotter than you expect it to be - so a "charger burning up" would be more likely to mean "gosh, my charger is much warmer than it should be", rather than "gosh, my charger is is on fire and will be consumed by it".

Comment: With phrasal verbs that are so close in meaning, the going can get rough. Mobile phones actually have caught fire. Please note: I merely explained that "burn up" can mean "consumed by fire" as a definition, and not that anyone would ever say that.